# `tensorflow_federated.learning.from_keras_model()` no longer contains 'dummy_batch' keyword?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I ran the tensorflow federated tutorial code on https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/federated/blob/v0.13.1/docs/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification.ipynb . I got this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-d5336a451ad0> in <module>()
      2     model_fn,
      3     client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.02),
----> 4     server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0))

2 frames
<ipython-input-16-7b97120f96c2> in model_fn()
      7       dummy_batch=sample_batch,
      8       loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
----> 9       metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

TypeError: from_keras_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dummy_batch'
```

The provided notebook updates the `tensorflow_federated` to latest version, so tff version is 0.14.0. So in version 0.14.0, we no longer need to feed the dummy batch? Is usual tff working pipline has changed?

P.S. Downgrading `tensorflow_federated` to version 0.13.1 works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct; the `dummy_batch` keyword was deprecated in [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/commit/8f07305ca36659e839aba45384e95837f955bebc) in favor of `input_spec`, for extra flexibility.

There are several ways one might get their hands on an `input_spec`, including computing it directly from the arrays or tensors to be fed into the model, but the simplest is to access the `element_spec` attribute of an associated `tf.data.Dataset` which the model will train on.

As for the link to the colab itself, looks like when TFF was updating its links as part of its release today, it forgot to include the `v` when tagging the commit on GitHub. Links are now updated, and [this](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/federated/blob/v0.14.0/docs/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification.ipynb) should take you to a version of the colab that works with 0.14.0.